# Finite and totally disconnected but not discrete space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Is there any example of a totally disconnected and finite topological space such that it is not discrete?

**Motivation**

So far I have not been able to find such space. Indeed, I have actually thought of an attempt at proving that it does not exists.

> Suppose that $X = \{x_{n}\}_{n \in \{0, 1, ..., N\}}$ is a finite topological space such that $\{x_0\}$ is not open. Then, since $X$ is finite, we can consider the smallest open set containing $X$, which is obtained from the intersection of all the neighborhoods of $x_0$. Let it be $A$ and note that it must contain more than one element. We claim $A$ to be connected. In fact, if $\{U,V\}$ is a separation of $A$, then WLOG we can assume $x_0 \in U$ and since $U$ is $A$-open we may write it as $U = U' \cap A$, where $U'$ is $X$-open. Hence, $U'$ being a neighborhood of $x_0$ implies $A \subseteq U'$ and $U = A$, which contradicts the assumption that $V$ be non-empty. In conclusion $A$ is connected and thus $X$ can not be totally disconnected.

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: A finite topological space which is not finite.  There is a typo.

Comment: A finite $T_1$ space is always discrete.  For a non $T_1$ finite space $X$ totally disconnectedness is enough to conclude $X$ is discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau) $ be totally disconnected topological space and $|X|<\infty$.

Since $X$ is totally disconnected, all components are singleton and components are closed implies every finite subsets of $X$ are closed.

Since $X$ is finite, every subsets of $X$ are closed implies $X$ is a discrete space.

Conclusion: A totally disconnected topological space where the underlying set is finite must be discrete.

Note: A finite $T_1$ space is always discrete.